# A short story about a girl remembering the day she got her brain implant

Tags: short-stories, story-identification

I am trying to find a short science fiction story I read about a year ago. The story was published on a site similar to "Daily Science Fiction", but I can't remember whether it was that specific site, or another.

The story begins with the girl, who is an university student, sitting in a white room with no decorations on the walls. The reason for there being nothing on the walls is the fact that she has a brain implant, which allows her to project anything on them on-demand.

She then starts thinking about the way the world was in the past. There is a Google Glass reference, where Glass is portrayed as the archaic technology that was the basis of what she now has in her brain.

Then, she recollects the day in which her mother got her to the hospital to "enhance" her. The mother tells the girl that she would have an advantage if she gets that, although the girl doesn't quite understand what is going to happen.

There is some minor surgery (having the advanced medical capabilities of the future), and then the girl remembers awaking in a room with a nurse. The girl doesn't feel very different initially.

Then the nurse activates her implant and the girl suddenly sees an object on the nurse's chest. The girl tries to touch that object, but the nurse tells her that she shouldn't touch it, since it contains private information about many patients. The nurse suggests that if the girl wants to see other people's lives, she could go online and look for public figures (Justin Bieber is mentioned).

There are also some other details - about the company that stores all the data in the cloud, the girl wondering how other people without implants functioned at all and so on, but I can't remember them all.

Has anyone come across this story? Could I get a link?

Comment: This is ringing vague bells... perhaps one of the radio plays on http://escapepod.org?

Comment: Well, I actually read it in a website (in text form). It could have been from the said site, but do you have something more concrete?

Comment: Nope (hence, this is a comment, not an answer :). But after a quick perusal, I think it might have been [In Loco Parentis](http://escapepod.org/2015/01/16/ep476-loco-parentis/)... though that's not a good enough match to your description (hence this also is a comment, not an answer :).

Comment: Somewhat similar, but not the same thing. In "In Loco Parentis" the girl is little, a schoolgirl, while in the story I'm looking for, the girl is already a university student and reflects on the past and on the development of tech altogether. It's not that personal.

Comment: I have the feeling that I read it on 365 tomorrows, but I already spent 2 days digging there and can't find it...

Comment: "The girl tries to touch that object, but the nurse tells her that she shouldn't touch it, since it contains private information about many patients." There might be some HIPAA issues there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally found it by applying some 15 filters on my outbox. Seems that my memory of where I read it was completely skewed :) It can be seen on ZDNet: ["Beyond Google Glass: 2034"](http://www.zdnet.com/article/beyond-google-glass-2034/)